# How do I conditionally add deploy step to .travis.yml when the branch is master and Travis is not building a pull request?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

In my .travis.yml file, I have a test and deploy stage.  I want to only execute the deploy stage if building a commit into master and not pull requests against master.

Current setup is like so:

```
stages:
- test
- deploy
matrix:
  include:
    -stage: test
       ...
    -stage: deploy
```

I would like to add something like:

```
stages:
- test
- deploy
  if: branch = master
matrix:
  include:
    -stage: test
      ...
    - stage: deploy
      ...
```

I can't seem to get the latter to work using the syntax found in Travis documentation: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

If you use the built-in Travis deployment, you can simply do this:

```
deploy
  --snip--
  on:
    branch: master
```

In the part I cut out (where it says `--snip--`), you would put your deployment provider.

More information [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this will run the deploy step for each stage in the matrix and not a single time after all stages have completed.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: What makes up your matrix?